# Convert Varchar to Datetime

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, functions, datetime, type-conversion

I have a database field Column_A  which is in Varchar(16) not null and the values are for example 20191210215033CS but I want to break it like 2019-12-10 21:50:33

Since it is a production database there is no way to change the data type.

Tried the below code

```
SELECT convert(datetime, 'Column_A', 120) but getting the error
```

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Is their any workaround ? Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: `SELECT convert(datetime, Column_A, 120)`

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.Get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Column_A' is not a date, Column_A may be.

```
Select convert(datetime,format(convert(bigint,left(Column_A,14)),
                               '####/##/## ##:##:##'))
```

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=39fc9472dc1f68b1d0e03bff48bf6686)

This ignores the 'CS' from your example. A kind of timezone?